# How to use when.map with node.lift-ed function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming, promise, when-js

I'm learning promises with `when.js` library, and using `when.map` with node `fs.readFile` makes me think I missed something. 
`foo` promise works ok when called as a single promise, but fails when used as a mapper function in `when.map` because index is injected as a third parameter (and then callback is passed as 4th).

API doc says that `when.map` has a requirement for mapper function to have two parameters. Then mapper function can be written as `bar`, and it works in any context.

```
var when = require('when');
var node = require('when/node');
var _ = require('lodash');

// readFile has the same signature as fs.loadFile
function readFile(param1, param2, callback) {
  console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
  callback(null, [param1, param2]);
}

var foo = _.partialRight(node.lift(readFile), 'base64');

var bar = function (fileName, index) {
  return node.lift(readFile)(fileName, 'base64');
};

when.map(['1', '2'], bar).done(); // works
when.map(['3', '4'], foo).done(); // does not work
```

Is there any more elegant way to write `bar` function?

Comment: I've seen `deferred` library has
    `promisify(fs.readFile, 1); // Restrict arity to 1 + callback`
that looks like what I need.

Comment: What you did (wrapping it in a lambda) is a perfectly fine solution is it not?

Answer (score 0):

I think you misinterpret the meaning of partialRight function.
Lodash documentation states for partialRight that

> This method is like _.partial except that partial arguments are
>   appended to those provided to the new function.

You, probably, thought that it is same as `curry` but goes from the right, but it's not! It will just append the extra arguments to the right of argument list:

```
function baz() {
    console.log(arguments)
}

var qux = _.partialRight(baz, 'should be second parameter, but is not')

console.log(qux("first parameter", "second parameter, should be ignored, but it's not!"))
```

which produces:

> ```
> { '0': 'first parameter',   '1': 'second parameter, should be ignored,
> but it\'s not!',   '2': 'should be second parameter, but is not' }
> ```

In lodash 3.0.0-pre there's function `curryRight` which you should try, in lodash 2.4.1 there're no such function, so I'm using dumb swap:

```
var when = require('when');
var node = require('when/node');
var _ = require('lodash');

function readFile(param1, param2, callback) {
  console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
  callback(null, [param1, param2]);
}


/* Swaps arguments of function with two arguments*/
function swap(f) {
    return function (a,b) {
        return f(b,a);
    }
}



var foo = _.curry(swap(node.lift(readFile)))("base64")



var bar = function (fileName, index) {
  return node.lift(readFile)(fileName, 'base64');
};



when.map(['1', '2'], bar).done(); // works
when.map(['3', '4'], foo).done(); // does work
```

BTW, thanks for Short, Self Contained, Correct Example!